Codeigniter Date comparison - Less than 24 Hours inside Models
I have the following queries in CodeIgniter to find any data in which the date_created field is less than 24 hours. Here is my code in Models
public function checkDeposit($preOrder) 
    {
        return $this->db->table('deposit')
        ->where('preorder_code', $preOrder)
        ->where('status', 0)
        ->where('date_created <', strtotime(date('YmdHis'), INTERVAL 1 DAY))
        ->get()
        ->getRowArray();
    }

But the above query is not working.
What I want in short is, return all rows which the date_created is less than 24 hours...
This is my date_created format
date_created Format
How to get data less than 24 hours in Models ?

First of all, you have a database structure problem.  Who ever decided on that datetime format opted for a column type that doesn't allow the seamless implementation of native SQL datetime functions.  I recommend, first correcting your database, then adjusting/simplifying your codebase.  Second, your PHP timestamp generating code doesn't even parse.  If you aren't going to use SQL functions, just use: strtotime('+1 DAY');

There are a couple of ways to do it:
->where('filters.created_at >', \CodeIgniter\I18n\Time::now()->subDays(1)->getTimestamp())
->where(new CodeIgniter\Database\RawSql('filters.created_at > UNIX_TIMESTAMP(NOW() - INTERVAL 1 DAY)'))
->where(new CodeIgniter\Database\RawSql('filters.created_at > UNIX_TIMESTAMP(DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 DAY))'))
->where('filters.created_at >', strtotime('-1 day'))
->where('filters.created_at >', (new \DateTimeImmutable())->modify('-1 day')->getTimestamp())
->where('filters.created_at >', (new \DateTimeImmutable())->sub(new \DateInterval('P1D'))->getTimestamp())
->where('filters.created_at >', date_timestamp_get(date_create('-1 day')))

Chose one of them.

The first one uses CodeIgniter Time class (I prefer this one, because it is a nice abstraction layer on top of built in PHP stuffs).
Second and third one uses MySQL Interval functions
The others use built in PHP functions like: strtotime, DateTimeImmutable

